# Raspberry Pi as slave

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c, communication, spi

I am using a Pi compute module and wish to make two of them to communicate to each other.

I have hooked up some slave I2C devices to it (RTC, Temperature sensor). So I don't think making Pi as slave using on-board I2C is an option

And I read [Understanding SPI on the Raspberry Pi](https://projects.drogon.net/understanding-spi-on-the-raspberry-pi/), on board SPI only function in Master mode.

I unable use Ethernet/Wifi/BT (design requirement not allow involving a LAN switch in between AND no USB wifi/bluetooth).

Is there any other way (maybe use the existing GPIO implementing my own software I2C/SPI/1wire slave?) to make both Pi communicate to each other? data speed is not important

**Updates**
Serial link TXD/RXD also already used up for communication with PC

Comment: A serial link perhaps?

Comment: sorry @joan, serial link already used up for PC-Pi communication

Comment: Doesn't the compute module have another serial link, e.g. on gpios 32/33.  You might have to search to find a Linux driver (I think one has been written) if you don't fancy writing a userland program to access the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the GPIO ports on the Pi and the RPi.GPIO API for Python to communicate and convert the number to binary, although this would take quite a bit of coding.

Another option would be to connect the two pis' directly to each other with just 1 ethernet cable, for which you would need to configure a default, static IP address to use on each. Then you could use the socket API from Python to communicate.

Comment: If you use an Ethernet cable to connect the Pis directly, I would think it should be a crossover cable - so that P1.Send -> P2.Receive (and vice versa) - at least that's the way it was done in the old days.