# could I Transfer the Video Data to Spi

Tags: camera, spi

The scenario uses two rasp's. 
One shoots video and the other plays video.
Communication Between Devices is SPI with 500kHz Clock.

1. Is it possible?

I don`t know how to get Video streaming from camera module V2 and put into data for play video.

2.Please refer to the recommended site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't communicate between two Pi's with the SPI bus.

For a SPI bus one end is a master the other end is a slave - you can't have both ends as a master.

The Pi hardware only supports operation as the SPI bus master.

Comment: I'm largely in agreement with this assessment, and I wouldn't recommend that anyone without large amounts of time and enthusiasm attempt running a Pi in SPI slave mode. Ghanima, in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36171/32756), links to a possible workaround which looks *clunky*.

Comment: @goobering As far as I am aware the Pi does not function as a SPI slave (the BSC/SPI slave peripheral simply does not work properly with SPI).  See my [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1052729#p1052729).

Answer (score 0):

it is hardly possible
if you use a third party spi device
lora wireless modules for example
which is a pretty add-on for your project

however the real problem is how to put camera data on spi bus

since spi is too slow for a good video transfer with low resolution and fps

sorry personal experience not a research

Answer (score 0):

A solution to preserve the data transfer rate is to use a data converter such as a 74HC595.
Connect SCLK to SRCK, SS (CS0..) to RCK and MOSI to SER. you can use the SS signal to trigger the second Raspberry
On the 74HC595, the G pin is connected to GND and the SRCLR pin to VDD.